# Understanding a step in solving a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm just getting into differential equations and I need some help understanding the following step shown in an example problem:

The problem goes from $t^7(\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{7}{t}y) = t^7t^2 $ to $\frac{d}{dt}(t^7 * y) = t^9$

What happens on the right side is an obvious result of simple exponent properties. WHat happens on the left side, however, is unclear to me. I have a feeling something is happening here that I learned in an earlier calculus course and am not remembering, but I have no idea what that might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
t^7 \left(\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac 7 t y \right) &= t^7 \frac{dy}{dt} + 7t^6 y \\
&= t^7 \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{dt^7}{dt} y \\
&= \frac d {dt} (t^7 y)
\end{align*}

according to the product rule.

Comment: My only understanding of the product rule is in the form of $f`(t)g(t) + f(t)g`(t)$. So in this case, $f(t) = t^7$, $f'(t) = 7t^6$, $g(t) = \frac{dy}{dt}$ - I follow all that in your answer. What I don't understand is how $g'(t)$ is just $\frac{dy}{dt}$ What happens to the $\frac{7}{t}y$ ?

Comment: Can we lose it because we're treating $y$ as a constant (because we're integrating $t$ not $y$), so $\frac{7}{t}$ is just a coefficient on a constant, therefore we drop it too?

Comment: No, $g(t) = y(t)$.

Comment: Ahh, yes of course, because you have $f'(t)g(t)$ on the right side of the + here. I still don't understand what's happening to the $\frac{7}{t}$ though. I'm beginning to think my misunderstanding is not rooted in basic calculus, it's something I'm not grasping about differentials.

Comment: The $7/t$ is multiplied by $t^7$ to get $7t^6$.

Comment: $t^7 \cdot \frac{7}{t} y = 7t^6 y$.  That's why $\frac{7}{t}$ appears on the left side of the equation--it's how you get $7t^6 y$ instead of $t^7 y$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Got it, wow, of course. Thanks for helping me realize I'm up too late.

Answer (score 1):

Differential equation:
\begin{align}\frac{7}{t}y+\frac{dy}{dt} &= t^2 \\ t^7\left(\frac{7}{t}y+\frac{dy}{dt}\right) &= t^7t^2 & \text{Multiply both sides of linear DE by $e^{\int7/t  \, dt} = t^7$} \\
\frac{d}{dt}(t^7y)&=t^9 & \text{Use product rule $\frac{d}{dt} (fg)=\frac{d}{dt}(f)g+f\frac{d}{dt}(g)$}
\end{align}

Product rule verification: \begin{align} \frac{d}{dt} (t^7 y) &= \frac{d}{dt}(t^7)(y) + (t^7) \frac{d}{dt}(y) \\ &= 7t^6y+t^7\frac{dy}{dt} \\
&= t^7\left(\frac{7}{t}y+\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\end{align}